# A proper website for theory in the gym?

Tags: exercise

I'm kind of new in the gym going through a bit of an information overflow period. I have a personal trainer which helps me with my form. However, I'm bad at remembering the names of different exercises. Is there a website or a pdf or something that includes most if not all exercises along with pictures or videos and maybe even what muscles do you use? Like a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

It is not comprehensive, but https://exrx.net/Lists/Directory covers a large swathe of the exercises people perform.